# iText copy form fields

Tags: java, pdf, forms, itext

Is there a way in iText to copy *just* the PDF acroform fields from one PDF document to another PDF document?  I have the code to copy the entire PDF, but I would like to be able to overlay all my fields to a new/updated PDF document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void replaceBackground(String newBackground, String CurrentForm, String newFile) throws Exception
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(newBackground);
            PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(CurrentForm);
            PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader2, new FileOutputStream(newFile));
            stamp.replacePage(reader, 1, 1);
            stamp.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite remember very well if we were able to achieve this since I was not directly working on the implementation but I remember pointing someone in this direction a while ago.

You may use the PdfStamper to extract fields out of the acroForm and then use the PdfWriter to create a new AcroForm with the pre-populated fields. I wish I could give you a better example but I don't quite have the code with me.

Comment: Milhous, could you please post a solution if you were able to figure it out. I am curious to know as well.